# How to change paddingStart and paddingEnd of the new Google Slider view

Tags: slider, android-view

As the title says, I would like to control the padding start and padding end (the red rectangle)

[image]

I've scanned the doc but nothing come out.

https://material.io/components/sliders/android#discrete-slider

Do you guy have any idea to change it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to by-pass the code here.

```
<dimen name="mtrl_slider_track_side_padding">0dp</dimen>
```

Comment: <dimen name="mtrl_slider_track_side_padding">0dp</dimen>